# pegar quem deu like no video youtube PHP API

Tags: php, youtube-api

Tem alguma maneira de receber informações de quem deu like em um determinado video? exemplo, joão deu like no video "Jogando aqui", ou melhor ainda, tem alguma maneira de saber quantos likes em videos joão já deu em todo canal?

Comment: Acredito que seja impossível, só da pra ver inscrições (se o perfil estiver publico) e compartilhamentos.

Answer (score 1):

Não tem como fazer isto sem que voce tenha instalado no  cliente uma api que monitore os passos do cliente, pela sua conta voce so tem como sabe se o perfil do usuario que te seguiu for publico e se seu perfil tambem for dai o proprio youtube te fornece isto.

Answer (score 1):

Isso não é possível, ao menos não dessa forma. O Google possui uma [API para YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication?hl=pt-br), é preciso que o usuário autorize isto, obviamente.

Se ele autorizar, você poderá usar a função "Retrieve the current user's rating of a video", [descrita aqui](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/getRating?hl=pt-br), ele irá retornar:

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/getRating

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoGetRatingResponse",
 "etag": "...",
 "items": [
  {
   "videoId": "...",
   "rating": "none"
  }
 ]
}
```

O `none` indica que eu nunca avaliei o vídeo, caso eu tenha dado algum like, ele será `"like"`, por exemplo.